# Click Once Deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

When I try and deploy my C# application as online only I'm getting this error that it can't find the applications manifest file, i've googled it read books on click once checked msdn and on here and I can't find out why it does this.

Downloading file:///C:/Documents and Settings/dale.waring/My Documents/Downloads/VM1_1_0_0_0/VM1.exe.manifest did not succeed.

- Could not find a part of the path 
  'C:\Documents and Settings\dale.waring\My Documents\Downloads\VM1_1_0_0_0\VM1.exe.manifest'.

Is it meant to download the manifest file from the publish location? All the files required are in the publish location so i'm not quite sure whats going on. Anybody else had this problem before?

Comment: Please make sure that manifest files must be generated while publishing the application. Properties-->Application-->Manifest box. Here you must see app.manifest file. Also, You can manually check it by browsing the path after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but doesn't the manifest file have to be in the same folder as the EXE?

Comment: I'm new to c# and I'm kind of in at the deep end here but I don't believe that is the case as when I make the application available offline and online it works and if I deploy it to cd.